# img tag doesnt print thumbnailed photo

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

im doing a project using .net MVC web Application.
i recently used a code to create a new thumbnail to photos (re defining the sizes of a photo) . and now i'm trying to print the photos using the 'img' tag of HTML but without success.
the thumbnail creating code :

```
Image thumbnail = Image.FromFile(destPath);
                thumbnail = (Image)(new Bitmap(thumbnail, new Size(this.m_thumbnailSize, this.m_thumbnailSize)));
                thumbnail.Save(destPathThumb);
```

now for the img printing :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem=>item)
                <img class="img-rounded" style="border-radius:50%" src=@item alt="">
```

item is the path to the picture and it is currect (ive checked serveral times).
any ideas what i could be ? 
thank you for helping me ! :)

EDIT: the img tag prints normal pictures -> pictures that my program did not create(as i said,my program created thumbnail pictures)

Comment: If you take the path that is printed from .net in your @item variable an paste it in the src attribute, is the image displayed on screen?
Is it a relative path or an absolute path ie starts with "/"?

Comment: I am not too familiar with MVC, but try putting quotations around the `@item` also check in browser using chrome dev tools to make sure it is tracing the image

Comment: it is the full path , and if i copy it instead of @item , the img tag still does not print it

Comment: Not super familiar with .net, however, does the DisplayFor() method render the image with the correct headers or any headers? Many times with rendering engines you need to include headers with the file ex: (content-type image/jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is not releasing the file lock on the image, I have had that problem in the past. You have to be very careful about releasing those Image and Bitmap objects.

Something like this might work, as it will dispose the image before the page starts using it:

```
using(Image thumbnailoriginal = Image.FromFile(destPath)){
    using(Image thumbnail = (Image)(new Bitmap(thumbnailoriginal, new Size(this.m_thumbnailSize, this.m_thumbnailSize)))){
        thumbnail.Save(destPathThumb);
    }
}
```

It seems like a lot of brackets on the end but thats ok.

If it still does not work, can you post the html that is sent to the browser, you can do that using "View page source" from the right-click menu in Chrome.

Comment: thank you for your answer ! , but where should i put that code ? inside the .net web page or on the c# page that creates the thumbnail      EDIT:  the second line of the code does not work , it writes : "cannot assign to 'thumbnail' because it is 'using variable'

Comment: c# page that creates the thumbnail. They are your 3 lines from the top of your question, I have just wrapped a using() around them.

Comment: Another thing to check is that you can access the image directly in the browser, so for instance the stackoverflow logo at the top of this page can be directly accessed here, there must be a similar url to your image:   https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=438582dc9e27

Comment: notice the edit that i wrote on my comment above , if you can please change the code to solve it .. coz i dont want to mess it up and prevent it form working like you did it :)

Comment: Yes, that is edited now, I did not notice that you were overwriting the first image with the second image. Now they both have different names so it might work!

Comment: it still does not print the image , i think that idea of file lock is probably it

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line after those 5 lines, so after the using is closed, and then try manually opening the file from File Explorer, does it let you, or is it still locked? Does it let you delete the file, that is a good test whether its locked. I have used this technique before and mine are safely unlocked so I think it should be fine.

Comment: i tried opening it from file explorer , and it worked .  the program that changes the files into thumbnail images is a windows service .

Comment: Then its not locked, so that side of it is solved. Now for the front-end, can you post the html that is sent to the browser, you can do that using "View page source" from the right-click menu in Chrome. Then we can check the img tag is fully formed and the url looks ok.

Comment: <img class="img-rounded" style="border-radius:50%" alt="" src="C:\Users\Operu\Desktop\dest\Thumbnails\2018\6\Sasuke.png">        (i could not make it into a code section)

Answer (score 0):

Now we have the html that is going to the browser, we can see that the src attribute is pulling directly from the C drive, rather than from a web url:

```
<img class="img-rounded" style="border-radius:50%" alt="" src="C:\Users\Operu\Desktop\dest\Thumbnails\2018\6\Sasuke.png">
```

Normally we would want to see something more like this:

```
<img class="img-rounded" style="border-radius:50%" alt="" src="\Thumbnails\Sasuke.png">
```

Could you post the model and controller files next please, so we can see what type of object the @item is when it hits your view. Then we can hopefully get it to pull the relative url address instead of the file location.

Comment: orah1998, did you solve this problem. If you did can you mark which answer worked for you so I can get my points above 50 please!